How to use -y and -W options together in SQLCMD to set variable length type display width and remove trailing spaces?
I’m trying to connect to a SQL Server using SQLCMD. While extracting data, one of my columns has a data length of 1500 characters. If I don’t specify the -y option, the data for this column is limited to 256 characters. However, when I specify the -y option to handle the longer data, I’m unable to use the -W option, which is causing incorrect column formatting.
sqlcmd  -S host,host -d sid -U user_name -P Password  -W  -y 8000

I've tried both options (-y and -W) together, but SQL throws the following error

W and y are mutually exclusive.

How can I set variable length type display width and remove trailing spaces?

-y "limits the number of characters that are returned for the large variable length data types". So instead of returning varchar(max), cast() or convert() to varchar(1500) if that is your max length and you may omit -y

Use a proper tool or library instead of trying to fight sqlcmd on columns which is just doesn't handle well
